# How to use variable declared in useEffect() in another function?

Tags: reactjs, canvas, react-hooks, use-effect, react-canvas

p.s solved the problem i was having, but i would still like to hear your thoughts on this and my code, if you have time :)

I can only assign a value to that variable ONLY after render has been completed, so i assume i must declare that variable in useEffect(), and it is impossible to assign value to it in global scope(which is executed before anything renders). But i also want to use that variable in another useEffect(), but i can't, since it's declared inside a function and it does not belong to global scope. 
Also, is it normal to have two useEffect -s? One i need for grabbing a context of canvas, and keeping that context consistent (not grabbing new one on every DOM update, as it happens when i don't put [] as second argument of first useEffect). And the other is for doing things with that unique context as state changes. Does it make sense? My code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { degreesToRadiansFlipped } from "./helpers/degreesToRadiansFlipped";
function Circle() {
  let [degree, setDegree] = useState(0);
  const canvas = useRef();
  const inputField = useRef();
  const coordinateX = Math.cos(degreesToRadiansFlipped(degree)) * 100 + 250;
  const coordinateY = Math.sin(degreesToRadiansFlipped(degree)) * 100 + 250;

  useEffect(() => {
    const context = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    drawCircle(context, coordinateX, coordinateY);
    return context;
    /*return function cleanUp() {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
      context.beginPath();
      drawCircle(context, coordinateX, coordinateY);
    };*/
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    drawCircle(context, coordinateX, coordinateY);
  }, [degree]);
  let drawCircle = function(context, x, y) {
    context.beginPath();
    //arc has option to make it anti-clockwise, making flipping radians redundant
    context.arc(250, 250, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.moveTo(250, 250);
    context.lineTo(x, y);
    context.stroke();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas ref={canvas} width={500} height={500}></canvas>
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setDegree(inputField.current.value);
        }}
      >
        <input type="text" ref={inputField}></input>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Circle;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes it makes sense to have multiples useEffect, when they have different arguments in the second parameter as you did.

you can declare the variable outside the useEffec as undefined.

```
let context = undefined // is not constant
  useEffect(() => {
    context = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    drawCircle(context, coordinateX, coordinateY);
    return context;
    /*return function cleanUp() {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
      context.beginPath();
      drawCircle(context, coordinateX, coordinateY);
    };*/
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    drawCircle(context, coordinateX, coordinateY);
  }, [degree]);
```

this way is available in the function scope

Answer (score 6):

If you declare the variable outside of `useEffect`, it will lose any assignment after each render.

A better approach is to use the `useRef` Hook and keep the mutable value in the `.current` property. Otherwise, it's best to keep it inside `useEffect`.